# How to add a new element in python LIST/DICT?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
data={
  'a':{'no':'1','lang':['uno','one']},
  'b':{'no':'2','lang':['due','two']},
  'c':{'no':'3','lang':['tre','three']}
}
print(data) #OK
print(data['a']['lang'][0]) #OK
data['d']['no']='4' #ERROR
data['d']['lang'][0]='quattro' #ERROR
data['d']['lang'][1]='four' #ERROR
print(data)
```

I would add **a new element** with a new master index 'd' with contents:

```
{'d':{'no':'4','lang':['quattro','four']}
```

But  I got an error on script for adding a new data element assignment below

```
.......
data['d']['no']='4' #ERROR
data['d']['lang'][0]='quattro' #ERROR
data['d']['lang'][1]='four' #ERROR
.......
```

Comment: How do you normally add an element? `data['d'] = ...`. Or you could use https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault, https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict, ...

Comment: data.append({'d':{'no':'4','lang':['quattro','four']}})

but still error

Comment: `data.append` wouldn't work, because dictionaries don't have that method. They're not lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data={
    'a':{'no':'1','lang':['uno','one']},
    'b':{'no':'2','lang':['due','two']},
    'c':{'no':'3','lang':['tre','three']}
}
data['d']={'no':'4','lang':['quattro','four']}
print(data)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error since you try to change a dictionary that does not exist,
your code would make sense if 'data['d']' were a dictionary but it doesn't exists yet,
try adding a new dictionary in the same format to 'data['d']' and that should fix your problem :)

```
data={
  'a':{'no':'1','lang':['uno','one']},
  'b':{'no':'2','lang':['due','two']},
  'c':{'no':'3','lang':['tre','three']}
}
print(data) #OK
print(data['a']['lang'][0]) #OK

data['d'] = {'no':'4','lang':['tre','three']} # the row i added 

data['d']['lang'][0]='quattro' #works now
print(data)
```

output:

```
{'a': {'no': '1', 'lang': ['uno', 'one']}, 'b': {'no': '2', 'lang': ['due', 'two']}, 'c': {'no': '3', 'lang': ['tre', 'three']}, 'd': {'no': '4', 'lang': ['quattro', 'three']}}
```